# Pseudo Element appearing momentarily after hover

Tags: html, css

I have animated arrows constructed with pseudo elements. When the link is hovered over, the arrows animate well but when the mouse leaves the link, there is pseudo element appearing on the top left of the screen for a brief moment after which it disappears. I am not able to figure why this is happening and which code is making this happen?

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.animated-arrow {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.the-arrow {
  width: 64px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.main .text {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow .shaft:before,
.left-arrow-float .the-arrow .shaft:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0;
}


/**************************************************/

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow.-left .shaft {
  width: 64px;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-left .shaft {
  width: 0px;
}

.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-left .shaft:before {
  width: 0px;
}

.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  width: 0px;
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow.-right .shaft {
  width: 0px;
}

.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-right .shaft {
  width: 64px;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow.-right .shaft:before {
  width: 0px;
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow.-right .shaft:after {
  width: 0px;
}

.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-right .shaft:before {
  width: 8px;
}

.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-right .shaft:after {
  width: 8px;
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow.-left .shaft:before,
.left-arrow-float .the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-arrow-float">

  <a class="animated-arrow arrow-c-f" href="#">

    <div class="left-arrow">

      <span class="main">
        <span class="the-arrow -left">
          <span class="shaft"></span>
      </span>

      <span class="text">
          Some Text
        </span>

      </span>

      <span class="the-arrow -right">
        <span class="shaft"></span>
      </span>
    </div>

  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: try setting `opacity:0` before and `opacity:1` after the animation for your arrow

Comment: _“I am not able to figure why this is happening”_ - start by increasing your transition durations and delays by a factor 10 or even 50, that gives you more time to inspect it. Add different (background-)colors to the pseudo elements, so that you can see which one of them causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all happening because you set some CSS at the wrong place...

```
.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-right .shaft {
  width: 64px;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

in the above css you set everythings on `hover`. you just need to set `width` on `hover` rest of the css will goes normally like below..

```
.left-arrow-float .the-arrow.-right .shaft {
  width: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-right .shaft {
  width: 64px;

}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.animated-arrow {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.the-arrow {
  width: 64px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.main .text {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow .shaft:before,
.left-arrow-float .the-arrow .shaft:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0;
}


/**************************************************/

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow.-left .shaft {
  width: 64px;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-left .shaft {
  width: 0px;
}

.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-left .shaft:before {
  width: 0px;
}

.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  width: 0px;
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow.-right .shaft {
  width: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-right .shaft {
  width: 64px;
  
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow.-right .shaft:before {
  width: 0px;
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow.-right .shaft:after {
  width: 0px;
}

.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-right .shaft:before {
  width: 8px;
}

.left-arrow-float .animated-arrow:hover .left-arrow .the-arrow.-right .shaft:after {
  width: 8px;
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.left-arrow-float .the-arrow.-left .shaft:before,
.left-arrow-float .the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-arrow-float">

  <a class="animated-arrow arrow-c-f" href="#">

    <div class="left-arrow">

      <span class="main">
        <span class="the-arrow -left">
          <span class="shaft"></span>
      </span>

      <span class="text">
          Some Text
        </span>

      </span>

      <span class="the-arrow -right">
        <span class="shaft"></span>
      </span>
    </div>

  </a>
</div>
```